# Best way to an occurrence in a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data containing tickets. All I want is to find how many of how many of those tickets have been assigned to **Fields Techs** in the Comment column. all the tickets got multiple entries(Comment).

```
field_tech=logs_data[logs_data['Comment'].str.contains('Assigned:Fields Techs')]

# calculate the length of the subset


len(field_tech)
```

I was actually thinking of grouping them by Comment, get a dataframe for every ticket, store them in a list and then do a looping through that list to get to get that my information. I know it's extensive computation but I do not really know how to confirm the what I have done and I do not know how to split all the results of my groupby in a list.

I think the correct SQL scripts  would be something like:

```
select tickets,Comment
from  logs
where Comment like 'Assigned:Fields Techs'
group by tickets
```

Comment: Can you share with us the expected output?

Comment: and also some sample input, maybe theres another column we could use?  is this also a user input field?  I worry about someone misspelling names and then you would get wrong counts.

Comment: here is the expected results: Total number of tickets assigned to field technicians: xxx

Comment: Your code looks fine. *What's the problem?*

Comment: @jpp . thanks I was just  sure. And was looking for another way to compare that result as I was not  sure of what I was getting

Comment: @Herc01, Can you share the dataFrame structure or what is desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was closed to the answer myself. I finally got it. 
Here is the answer:

```
logs_data[logs_data['Comment'].str.contains('Assigned:FieldsTechs')].groupby('Ticket')

 # Then I just get the length of the above for number of tickets assigned to tecks.

len(logs_data[logs_data['Comment'].str.contains('Assigned:Fields Techs')].groupby('Ticket'))
```

Comment: @ Herc01, glad you got ans yourself.

Comment: even you can try `('Assigned:*Techs$')` if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You current code looks good, However if you looking for few little tricks to make it reall tricky the it may also be considered as follows:

```
field_tech=logs_data[logs_data['Comment'].str.contains('Assigned:*Techs$')]
```

In the above code of line if we  know ticket type is always `Assigned:Fields Techs`, so we can trim it like so, saying ticket name starting as `Assigned` & always ending with `Techs` hence we don't put the whole things.

```
field_tech=logs_data[logs_data['Comment'].str.startswith('Assigned:Fields Techs')]
```

In the above second line of code we are using string which startswith which will also work.

Comment: actually my code  is wrong I just made a simulation by created a dataframe. I am counting the string in a particular column that's it. I need to  group them by tickets. At the moment I am also counting duplicated tickets

Comment: @Herc01, in order to get the correct answer you need to show at least minimal code and desired result.